# cannot add track to a playlist - spotipy - python

Tags: python-3.x, spotipy

I am working on Musical Time Machine Project as shown in 100 Days of Code: Python by Angela Yu.
Project Description: Find songs on the top 100 Billboard charts on any date, search those songs on Spotify, and create a personalised playlist.
I am using python's Spotify library called spotipy, instead of Spotify Web API.

Problem: I have created the Chart, and authenticated on Spotify. Created a playlist but cannot add the tracks in the playlist.

```
def search_id(artist: str, track: str) -> str:
    return sp.search(q=f"artist:{artist} track:{track}", type="track", limit=1)["tracks"]["items"][0]["uri"]

# Creates a new playlist
playlist_id = sp.user_playlist_create(user=USER_ID,
                                      name=f"{charts.charts['Time Machine']}",
                                      public=False,
                                      description="None ")["id"]

sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=playlist_id, items=search_id(artist="Seedhe Maut", track="Kyu"))
```

Exceptions:

```
    raise SpotifyException(400, -1, "Unsupported URL / URI.")
spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 400, code:-1 - Unsupported URL / URI., reason: None
```

I cannot understand the reason. Tried doing many things, but still raised the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your `search_id()` function returns a string, but `sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=playlist_id, items=[])` requires a [list] of strings, as you can [read here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/#spotipy.client.Spotify.playlist).
To solve your problem, you should put brackets around `items=[search_id()]`.